How to disable the text suggestion for a MahApps-Metro textbox
While typing text into a MahApps Textbox, auto suggested text pops up by default. How can this feature be disabled?
Here an example:

        <TextBox 
            Text="{Binding Title}"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
            Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.TextBox}"
            mah:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True"
            mah:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Kurzbezeichnung der Fundstelle"         
            />



if you under Windows 11 then this is an built in feature of the OS itself: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-text-suggestions-in-windows
